# How can I repair video when I cannot see the screen?

Tags: 14.04

Background:
I have an old 1.6 Ghz pc 2GB RAM with an NVIDIA GeForce FX 5500 graphics card and a Broadcom 4318 WiFi. One drive is Pata and one is Sata. One contains XP and one had an NTFS partition for XP and a partition for Ubuntu 12.04 and many earlier versions.  I used GParted to shrink the 12.04 partition to make room for 14.04. After install I did not see it appear in the GRUB menu until 12.04 upgraded from -64 to -65.

Then three choices appeared for 14.04:

```
Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os 'gnulinux-simple-UUID ->
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class gnu-linux --class gnu ----class os 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-ge->
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)'  --class ubuntu --class gnu --class os 'gnuli->
```

The lines are incomplete because they were off my screen but all referred to 1.13.0-24. Both hard drives have the boot flag set and I think sdb is the second drive with only XP on it. I think sda2 has 12.04 and sda5, 14.04.

After they showed up I activated the Wi-Fi with:

```
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

Because 14.04 was exceedingly slow, I found:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/first
which described how to disable 3D graphics among other things which it said to do in the order given. Step 2 recommended replacing the graphics driver and I had already done that in 12.04 to NVIDIA-173.14.39 so that step seemed perfectly reasonable. After the reboot in step 1.5e the screen stayed blank.

By booting into 12.04 I can see that the 4 lines were added in:
`/etc/sysctl.conf` regarding `vm.swappiness` and `vm.vfs_cache_pressure`.

So that is how I got here.  I can *read/write* all the 14.04 files from 12.04 and can get to the root terminal by booting in the recovery mode.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get nvidia-uninstall
```

in hopes that I could revert to `nouveau`.  Slow is better than blind.
I can reallocate the partition with 14.04 and start over but am hoping for another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Metacity does now work with Nouveau after again installing and purging Nvidia

[Oh yes, and copying `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` from 12.04 to 14.04 - which may have had nothing at all to do with the final success.  In case it did here are the contents:

```
 Section "Screen"  
  Identifier "Default Screen"  
  DefaultDepth 24  
  Option "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP" #see https://help.ubuntu.comcommunity/VideoDriverHowto/Nvidia  
EndSection  
>Section "Module"  
    Load    "glx"  
EndSection  

>Section "Device"  
    Identifier  "Default Device"  
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"  
        #   Driver  "nvidia"  
EndSection
].
```

Many thanks to the authors of the postings I have read.  Especially helpful was the magic <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> incantation that brings up a terminal.